# How to deploy angularjs with nodejs as backend requesting server, after building the angularjs package

Tags: angularjs, node.js, parse-platform

How to deploy angularjs with nodejs as backend requesting server, after building the angularjs package

My project structure:
app/
app/config
app/scripts
app/styles
app/views
bower_components/
dist/
node_modules/
test/
server.js

After building the angular package using grunt, i am using only the dist folder. But i want to use node for my request, to server. So how to setup the nodejs packages inside dist build folder. Which will be deployed to parse.com

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need a simple webserver which is always returning index.html + the assets.

If I'm right in your root (i guess `/dist` at this point) you have to create an app.js file containing the following:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var path = require('path')
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    if (path.extname(req.path).length > 0) {
         // normal static file request
         next();
     }
     else {
         // should force return `index.html` for angular.js
         req.url = '/index.html';
         next();
     }
});
// static file serve
app.use(express.static(__dirname))
app.listen(3000)
```

Comment: As you said, when i creating a app.js means i will not get any dependencies. If i open the dist folder - for example in wamp server - it will automatically open in browser. Here node is not started and also it will not have dependencies. Please suggests in this. Thanks for your reply :-)

Comment: If you want node, you don't have to use wamp.  I don't get the mix. Basically when creating your dist folder, you have to copy/paste the file i wrote above here plus a package.json. And then in the server you will have to do `npm install` and `node app.js`